# VBA- How do you select a column's cells that have value

Tags: c#, vba

I'm working on this method that filters 2 columns to find the rows with different values, select the values in these columns, and color the cell areas yellow. I'm having trouble selecting the values properly. For some reason none of the selection methods I'm using now don't work properly. The range values are single cells, I'm trying to select the entire used range of the column. They either do not select the entire used range, or select the entire column including blank cells, or color cells at the very bottom of the sheet. Here is my code sample:

```
static public void FilterFunction(Excel.Application Oxl, Excel.Worksheet PSheet, Excel.Range Rng, Excel.Range Find)
    {
        Excel.Range Filler = null;
        Rng.AutoFilter(Rng.Column, "Found");
        Find.AutoFilter(Find.Column, "Missing");
        Rng.Columns.Select();
        Filler = Oxl.Selection as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        Find.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown].Select();
        Filler = Oxl.Selection as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        Rng.AutoFilter(Rng.Column, "Missing");
        Find.AutoFilter(Find.Column, "Found");
        Rng.EntireColumn.Select();
        Filler = Oxl.Selection as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        Find.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown].Select();
        Filler = Oxl.Selection as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        PSheet.ShowAllData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with the solution myself. I took advantage of the `UsedRange` property for the worksheet, and selected the column with my range value in it, giving me a range with all the cells in one column that have values in it. I had the headers (`Rng`, `Find`) highlighted in yellow, so I used the range values for the headers to turn them back to white.

```
static public void FilterFunction(Excel.Application Oxl, Excel.Worksheet PSheet, Excel.Range Rng, Excel.Range Find)
    {
        Excel.Range Filler = null;
        PSheet.Activate();
        Rng.AutoFilter(Rng.Column, "Found");
        Find.AutoFilter(Find.Column, "Missing");
        Filler = PSheet.UsedRange.Columns[Rng.Column] as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Columns.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        Filler = PSheet.UsedRange.Columns[Find.Column] as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Columns.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        Rng.AutoFilter(Rng.Column, "Missing");
        Find.AutoFilter(Find.Column, "Found");
        Filler = PSheet.UsedRange.Columns[Rng.Column] as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Columns.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        Filler = PSheet.UsedRange.Columns[Find.Column] as Excel.Range;
        Filler.Columns.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Yellow);
        Rng.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.White);
        Find.Cells.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.White);
        PSheet.ShowAllData();
    }
```